# Text inside SliderThumbStyle

Tags: wpf, slider, styles

So this is my `SliderThumbStyle` `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="outerBorder"
                                Background="{DynamicResource LabelDisableForegroundColor}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource LabelDisableForegroundColor}"
                                Height="20"
                                Width="20"
                                Opacity="1" 
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                CornerRadius="8"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="sliderValue"
                                   FontSize="11"
                                   Foreground="Silver"
                                   Text="{Binding }"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And as you can see i put inside the `Thumb` a simple `TextBlock` in oder to see the current `Slider value`

What i need to put inside the Text `property`:

```
Text="{Binding }"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work provided that the `Thumb` is a visual child of the `Slider`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Slider}}" />
```